# Cin not producing required results

Tags: c++

i'm trying to set up a simple flight booking system program, but my second bit of cin code is not calling for input when i run the program. Unlike the initial cin that requires your name initially. the program just runs and returns 0. I'm a beginner at c++ and i know this is a simple fix so please be understanding . Thank you any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int name;
    int Seatnumber;
    int optionnumber = 1-5 ;
    std::string out_string;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << optionnumber;
    out_string = ss.str();

    cout << "Welcome to the COS1511 Flight Booking System" "\n" << endl;
    cout << "Enter full name : " << endl;
    cin >> name ; "\n";

    cout << "\n" "The Available travel times for flights are:" << endl;
    cout << "         Depart                Arrive" << endl;
    cout << "1.       7.00                  9.30"  << endl;
    cout << "2.       9.00                  11.30" << endl;
    cout << "3.       11.00                 13.30" << endl;
    cout << "4.       13.00                 15.30" << endl;
    cout << "5.       15.00                 17.30" << endl;
    cout << "Choose the time by entering the option number from the displayed list : " << endl;

    cin >> optionnumber ;

    if (optionnumber == 1-5){
        cout << "\n" "The available seats for are as follows " << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Incorrect option! Please Choose from 1-5 " << endl;

        cout << "First Class(1920)" << endl;
        cout << "|A1||A2||A3|----|A4||A5||A6|" << endl;
        cout << "|B1||B2||B3|----|B4||B5||B6|" << endl;
        cout << "|C1||C2||C3|----|C4||C5||C6|" << endl;
        cout << "|D1||D2||D3|----|D4||D5||D6|" << endl;
        cout << "| Economy Class(1600)" << endl;
        cout << "|E1||E2||E3|----|E4||E5||E6|" << endl;
        cout << "|F1||F2||F3|----|F4||F5||F6|" << endl;
        cout << "|G1||G2||G3|----|G4||G5||G6|" << endl;
        cout << "|H1||H2||H3|----|H4||H5||H6|" << endl;
        cout << "|I1||I2|" << endl;
        cout << "Please Key in a seat number to choose a seat(eg: A2)" << endl;
        cin >> Seatnumber;
}
```

1. prompt the user to enter their name.
2. Then display a menu showing the available times for the flight.
   the user can choose a preferred departure time(option 1-5)
   the option selected should be validated for 1-5
3. if the user entered the correct time a seating arrangement for that particular flight time should be displayed to the next user for the user to choose a seat.

Comment: `if (optionnumber == 1-5)`  does not what you expected, see my answer

Comment: I strongly recommend using [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) rather than `std::cin >> whatever;` for line-oriented input.

Comment: I supposed my answer solved your question, this is not the case ?

Answer (score 1):

Warning

> ```
> int optionnumber = 1-5 ;
> ```

does

```
int optionnumber = -4 ;
```

and

> ```
> if (optionnumber == 1-5){
> ```

does

```
if (optionnumber == -4){
```

but you wanted `if ((optionnumber >= 1) && (optionnumber <= 5))`

> if the user entered the correct time a seating arrangement for that particular flight time should be displayed to the next user for the user to choose a seat.

No, whatever the result of the test above you continue and write `"First Class(1920)"` etc so even when the choice is invalid

---

in

> ```
>   cin >> name ; "\n";
> ```

what did you expect about the `"\n"` ?

I encourage you to check the read success, currently if the user does not enter an integer you do not know that

But are you sure the name must be an integer ? Probably it must be s *string*

---

`out_string` is unused, it can be removed

---

Visibly *Seatnumber* is not an *int* but a *string* (A1 ...)

---

you probably want to loop until a valid time is enter, also fixing the other problems a solution can be :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string name;
  string Seatnumber;
  int optionnumber;

  cout << "Welcome to the COS1511 Flight Booking System" "\n" << endl;
  cout << "Enter full name : " << endl;

  if (!(cin >> name))
    // EOF (input from a file)
    return -1;

  cout << "\n" "The Available travel times for flights are:" << endl;
  cout << "         Depart                Arrive" << endl;
  cout << "1.       7.00                  9.30"  << endl;
  cout << "2.       9.00                  11.30" << endl;
  cout << "3.       11.00                 13.30" << endl;
  cout << "4.       13.00                 15.30" << endl;
  cout << "5.       15.00                 17.30" << endl;
  cout << "Choose the time by entering the option number from the displayed list : " << endl;

  for (;;) {
    if (!(cin >> optionnumber)) {
      // not an int
      cin.clear(); // clear error

      string s;

      // flush invalid input
      if (!(cin >> s)) 
        // EOF (input from a file)
        return -1;
    }
    else if ((optionnumber >= 1) && (optionnumber <= 5))
      // valid choice
      break;

    cout << "Incorrect option! Please Choose from 1-5 " << endl;
  }

  cout << "\n" "The available seats for are as follows " << endl;
  cout << "First Class(1920)" << endl;
  cout << "|A1||A2||A3|----|A4||A5||A6|" << endl;
  cout << "|B1||B2||B3|----|B4||B5||B6|" << endl;
  cout << "|C1||C2||C3|----|C4||C5||C6|" << endl;
  cout << "|D1||D2||D3|----|D4||D5||D6|" << endl;
  cout << "| Economy Class(1600)" << endl;
  cout << "|E1||E2||E3|----|E4||E5||E6|" << endl;
  cout << "|F1||F2||F3|----|F4||F5||F6|" << endl;
  cout << "|G1||G2||G3|----|G4||G5||G6|" << endl;
  cout << "|H1||H2||H3|----|H4||H5||H6|" << endl;
  cout << "|I1||I2|" << endl;

  cout << "Please Key in a seat number to choose a seat(eg: A2)" << endl;
  cin >> Seatnumber;

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall cc.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Welcome to the COS1511 Flight Booking System

Enter full name : 
bruno

The Available travel times for flights are:
         Depart                Arrive
1.       7.00                  9.30
2.       9.00                  11.30
3.       11.00                 13.30
4.       13.00                 15.30
5.       15.00                 17.30
Choose the time by entering the option number from the displayed list : 
aze
Incorrect option! Please Choose from 1-5 
7
Incorrect option! Please Choose from 1-5 
2

The available seats for are as follows 
First Class(1920)
|A1||A2||A3|----|A4||A5||A6|
|B1||B2||B3|----|B4||B5||B6|
|C1||C2||C3|----|C4||C5||C6|
|D1||D2||D3|----|D4||D5||D6|
| Economy Class(1600)
|E1||E2||E3|----|E4||E5||E6|
|F1||F2||F3|----|F4||F5||F6|
|G1||G2||G3|----|G4||G5||G6|
|H1||H2||H3|----|H4||H5||H6|
|I1||I2|
Please Key in a seat number to choose a seat(eg: A2)
qsd
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Note entering the name with `cin >> name` does not allow it to contain several names separated by a space, to allow composed name *getline* can be used

Comment: yes i'm an idiot. I declared name as an integer. I often spend hours stuck looking for a stupid mistake such as this. Thanks for the help its working perfectly.